# How to define MQTT client id with kafka connect

Tags: apache-kafka, mqtt, apache-kafka-connect

I want to create a bridge between a MQTT queue and a Kafka queue, to do this I want to use kafka connect, however to connect to the MQTT queue I need to use a specific identifier but I can't find where to indicate this because I can't find any mqtt_client_id property in the kafka mqtt connector documentation [https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-mqtt/current/mqtt-source-connector/mqtt_source_connector_config.html#mqtt-source-connector-config]. But I think it is possible because in the connector code there is a property MQTT_CLIENT_ID: https://github.com/evokly/kafka-connect-mqtt/blob/master/src/main/java/com/evokly/kafka/connect/mqtt/MqttSourceConnectorConfig.java.

Here are the properties I use:

```
{
    "name": "mqtt-source",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.mqtt.MqttSourceConnector",
        "tasks.max": 1,
        "mqtt.server.uri": "tcp://my.uri.com:1883",
        "mqtt.topics": "/topic/#",
        "mqtt.username" : "username",
        "mqtt.password" : "password",
        "kafka.topic": "mqtt-events",
        "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter",
        "confluent.topic.bootstrap.servers": "kafka:9092",
        "confluent.topic.replication.factor": 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Confluent MQTT connector is different from the one you found, and is not open source.

Therefore, I'd trust the documentation on available configurations

Comment: OK, there is no way to tell the MQTT Confluent connector which MQTT identifier to use ?  I should probably try to use the opensource one

Comment: Like I said, it's not open source, and I don't work for Confluent, so there's no way for me to answer that